# Simulate response variable y for given tau = 0.5 and X values in quantile regression

Tags: r, regression, simulation, non-linear-regression

I am trying to simulate data with `tau = 0.5`. I am using the following `r code` to simulate data.

```
#rm(list=ls())
library(quantreg)
set.seed(12)
n = 100
tau = 0.5

u <- runif(n)
z <- rbinom(n, 1, 0.37)
v <- rnorm(n)
d <- z * (u > 0.5 * v)

x <- runif(n, 0, 1) 
x1 <- (u - tau) + x * 2 
y <- (1 - d) * x + d * x1
```

Does it correct? Also, are there any `r` function available to simulate `y` for given `x` and `tau` values? I noticed `arima.sim()` available to simulate time series data.

Comment: Are you trying to create some data? If you are using quantreg, tau is the quantile, so tau=0.5 is the median. You want to generate some data whose median is 0.5?

Comment: @SimonWoodward, Yes I want to generate data for different `tau` values. For example, `tau = 0.5`.